# How to make this Javascript redirect the user to a different page on success instead of sliding up a panel

Tags: javascript

Ok so im not good at Javascript.  But I have inherited this piece in an existing web page and I now need to alter its behaviour.  At the moment on succesfully completing the form, a pane slides up telling the user that their info has been received etc.  If they miss a field or type something wrong, then it displays the error.  The actual validation for the form is done in php, but its output is displayed using this javascript segment.

I want to continue using the existing script to display errors in a slide up pane, but if the form is filled in correctly i now want the user to be re-directed to a new page.
I thought putting window.location ('new page') at the end would work.... but it doesn't

Can someone tell me what part of this code is the equivalent of "if succesful do this...."

See code below...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /*ajax form*/
    $('#formCallback').submit(function(){

        //var opt = $("#chkTCs").is(':checked') ? $("#chkTCs").val() : null;

        var action = $(this).attr('action');

        $('#formCallback #submit').attr('disabled','disabled').after('<img src="../resources/images/indicator.gif" class="loader" />');

        $("#message").slideUp(750,function() {
        $('#message').hide();

        $.post(action, { 
            txtName: $('#txtName').val(),
            txtSurname: $('#txtSurname').val(),
            txtEmail: $('#txtEmail').val(),
            txtNumber: $('#txtNumber').val(),
            txtPostcode: $('#txtPostcode').val(),
            //chkTCs: opt,
            verify: $('#verify').val()
        },
            function(data){
                document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
                $('#message').slideDown('slow');
                $('#formCallback img.loader').fadeOut('fast',function(){$(this).remove()});
                $('#formCallback #submit').attr('disabled',''); 
                if(data.match('success') != null) $('#success.pho').slideUp('slow');    
            }
        );

        });

        return false;

    });
    /*ajax form*/

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
 if(data.match('success') != null) $('#success.pho').slideUp('slow');
```

To this:

```
if(data.match('success') != null){
    document.location.href = "www.someexamplesite.com";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you inherited some s****y code and now you need to add a new functionality right? This is actually a great opportunity to learn new things, e.g.:

1) Readability counts, which one do you prefer?

This one:

```
$.post(action, { 
        txtName: $('#txtName').val(),
        txtSurname: $('#txtSurname').val(),
        txtEmail: $('#txtEmail').val(),
        txtNumber: $('#txtNumber').val(),
        txtPostcode: $('#txtPostcode').val(),
        //chkTCs: opt,
        verify: $('#verify').val()
    },
        function(data){
            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
            $('#message').slideDown('slow');
            $('#formCallback img.loader').fadeOut('fast',function(){$(this).remove()});
            $('#formCallback #submit').attr('disabled',''); 
            if(data.match('success') != null) $('#success.pho').slideUp('slow');    
        }
    );

    });
```

Or this one?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: action,
    data: {
        txtName: $('#txtName').val(),
        txtSurname: $('#txtSurname').val(),
        txtEmail: $('#txtEmail').val(),
        txtNumber: $('#txtNumber').val(),
        txtPostcode: $('#txtPostcode').val(),
        //chkTCs: opt,
        verify: $('#verify').val()
    },
    success: function (data) {
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
        $('#message').slideDown('slow');
        $('#formCallback img.loader').fadeOut('fast',function(){$(this).remove()});
        $('#formCallback #submit').attr('disabled',''); 
        if(data.match('success') != null) $('#success.pho').slideUp('slow');
    }
});
```

2) Avoid bipolar programming. If you are using jQuery **then use jQuery!**

```
document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
$('#message').slideDown('slow');
```

Replace this `document.getElementById('message')` with this `$('#message')`.

Now, to answer your question: If you want to redirect the user after the animated message shows up you can use this:

```
success: function (data) {
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
    $('#message').slideDown('slow');
    $('#formCallback img.loader').fadeOut('fast',function(){$(this).remove()});
    $('#formCallback #submit').attr('disabled',''); 
    if(data.match('success')) {        
        $('#success.pho').slideUp('slow', function() {
            // Animation complete.
            window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
        }
    }    
}
```